# Expression for coupon collector is giving wrong output

Tags: c++, probability

This is coupon collector problem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector's_problem
problem-http://www.spoj.com/problems/FAVDICE/

```
 y=n*log(n)+0.5*n+0.5;
```

edit:
Expected output is 37.24 while it is giving 35.82 for n=12
What could be error in the expression?

Comment: It is, by definition, giving the correct output. Computers don't randomly decide to be "wrong" on some particular day. It must therefore be your expectations that are at fault, of either the maths or the programming language. Unfortunately, you neglected to explain said expectations, so we have no means to correct them.

Comment: How should we know? You didn't give us any background or context on what you are working on. Did you mean `std::log10` instead of `std::log` (which is `ln`)

Comment: @CoryKramer: Unfortunately, the Wikipedia article is ambiguous as to the base in use.

Comment: Plot twist: the result, for me, is `36.3189`. Time to present a [testcase](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and _prove_ that the result should be `37.24`. Actually, you should have done that in the first place.

Comment: Your last edit did little else but remove a crucial detail from the question (the value for _n_). May I please recommend that you stop for a moment, take a deep breath, and have a little think about what you're doing, both with the original problem and with this question submission?

Comment: edited again    @LightnessRacesinOrbit

Comment: You're not listening.

Answer (score 1):

Go back to the Wikipedia article; check your value for gamma

```
const float GAMMA = 0.577215664;
y=n*log(n)+GAMMA*n+0.5;
```

output

```
37.2455
```

or better yet cut out gamma alltogether

```
double H(int n){
    double sum = 0.0;
    for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
        sum += 1/double(i);
    }
    return sum;
}
...
cout << setprecision(4) << n*H(n);
```

Comment: but then it is not giving correct value for n=1